# kafka consumer fetching different offset when rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

i have 1 micro service application that develop using camel-kafka to consuming the message from kafka.
i run this service with 4 concurrent instance where each of them having 1 consumer that consume from the topic that have 20 partitions.

During the maintenance period (daily 1-2am), the application will pause the consumption by stopping the consumer.

when the application is pause the consumption, the kafka rebalancing is happened and some instance will get assigned with more partition before it stop the consumer.

e.g partition that consume by instanceA (partition1-5) will be re-assigned to instanceB and then re-assigned to instanceC until all the instance is shutdown the consumer.

the issue come after application startup the consumer, some of the instance is being reprocess the message from kafka again even there is no new message that being publish to the topic.

upon checking the log, notice that when the rebalancing during the application stop, the offset = 12399, but when the application is starting to consume the message, the offset = 12336.

```
November 17th 2020, 01:00:02.951 | test-679656954c-5pssk | [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-17, groupId=group1] Setting offset for partition TestTopic-14 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=12399, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[testbroker1.local:9093 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=6}}
November 17th 2020, 02:00:00.559 | test-679656954c-j4xbl | [Consumer clientId=consumer-group1-17, groupId=group1] Setting offset for partition TestTopic-14 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=12336, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[testbroker1.local:9093 (id: 1 rack: null)], epoch=6}}
```

is that anyway to check how the offset is being changed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that during the shutdown phase, the 4 concurrent instances are shut down one by one and this is why you see a rebalance of the partitions assigning the ones from the first shutting down instance to the other instances that are still running, and so on.
Regarding the offset on startup, it depends on how the consumers are committing the offset. If the autocommit is enabled it happens periodically, so it's possible that when shutdown happens, the commit isn't done (because periodic) and the latest offset is not committed. If you are using manual commit, before shutting down you should be sure from inside the application that all consumers have committed the offsets for the consumed messages.

Comment: The strange thing is when it get rebalance during the shutdown, the partition rebalance to instance B showing that the offset = 12399, where i assume that the last commit from the instance A is 12399, but when the application is starting up 1 hour later, the consumer that consuming that particular topic is getting offset which is 12336 which lesser than previous committed offset.

Comment: are you sure that 12399 is the last committed offset? Or is it just the last consumed offset? How do you know that it's the last committed if you say that are using the auto commit? As far as I know there is no way to know what is the last committed offset when it's autocommitted.

Comment: i'm not sure, i just assume that offset is the last offset as it show when it get rebalance by other instance. but just curios, is that possible for a consumer to consume from different offset 12399 while the previous instance is not committing the offset as i'm using earliest offset.

Comment: a consumer in a consumer group getting a partition can start only from the latest committed offset (if there is no committed offset then the earliest or latest policy applies). Tbh the log could be misleading but I think that during the shutdown the commit was not done.

Comment: i see.. if my consumer is only consuming 1 message each time with 1s interval autocommit, but right if the commit is failed, isn't that the commit should have only 1 offset different? besides that, there is no transaction for that partition in certain period before the instance shutdown. will the autocommit is done as batch even the consumer is consume the msg 1 by 1 ?

Comment: the commit is done in a kind of "batch". It means that if you consume 10 messages, on the auto commit execution it will commit the offset of last message of the 10, and not doing 10 commits one by one.